# Mapping List<Model> to Dictionary<int, ViewModel>

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a model class:

```
public class Model {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and a view model:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to map List to Dictionary where the key will be Model.Id.

I have started with such configuration:

```
configuration
    .CreateMap<Model, KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>>()
    .ConstructUsing(
        x =>
            new KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>(x.Id, _mapper.Map<ViewModel>(x)));
```

But I don't want to use mapper instance in the configuration. Is there any other way to achieve this? I've seen some answers, where people used x.MapTo(), but that doesn't seem to be available anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by @hazevich stopped working after 5.0 update. This is working solution.

---

You need to create a type converter:

```
public class ToDictionaryConverter : ITypeConverter<Model, KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>>
{
    public KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel> Convert(Model source, KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>(source.Id, context.Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(source));
    }
}
```

and then use it in the configuration:

```
configuration
    .CreateMap<Model, KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<ToDictionaryConverter>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mapper instance from lambda parameter `x.Engine.Mapper`

Simple as this

```
configuration
    .CreateMap<Model, KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>>()
    .ConstructUsing(context => new KeyValuePair<int, ViewModel>(
        ((Model)context.SourceValue).Id,
        context.Engine.Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(context.SourceValue)));
```

Comment: Thanks - looks great, but I think I am missing some reference - I get errors during compilation (even though IntelliSense works fine):


'ResolutionContext' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and 
'QuotationPosition' does not contain a definition for 'Engine'

Comment: I found the problem - the lambda param can be either a Model or Context. It should be context here. I have updated your code and it works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichalDymel glad it helped :)